# tasks.json won't compile multiple source files

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code

Following the instructions from [this link on configuring c++ with vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_modifying-tasksjson), I set up my tasks.json file to compile multiple files in one directory. However, I always get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccXey2PG.o: in function `main':
bigone.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `swag()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From what I understand, this error basically means that my function definition file swag.cpp isn't getting included in compilation. I've tried the solutiosn from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720769/how-to-use-visual-studio-code-to-compile-multi-cpp-file), but nothing seems to work.

Also, if I just compile and run the files directly in the terminal through `g++ swag.cpp bigone.cpp` and `./a.out`, everything works fine and dandy.

Any suggestions? I should probably just be using make files, but the fact that I can't figure this out is getting my knickers in a knot. Thanks for the help, as always.

Here's my code:

bigone.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "swag.h"

int main()
{
    swag();
    return 0;
}
```

swag.h:

```
#pragma once
void swag();
```

swag.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
void swag()
{
    std::cout << "swag" << "\n";
}
```

And here's my tasks.json file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": ["-g", "${fileDirname}/*.cpp", "-o", "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "/usr/bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: By the time multiple source files come into play, getting yourself a build system is better. cmake with its extension, or the built-in make support. While it's possible to make tasks.json do this, it's hacky.

Comment: the method **sweenish** comments is the best way to go, but does the terminal show that g++ is compiling multiple `.cpp` files

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by  show? I'm not sure if this counts, but here's what's going on in my terminal:

`~/Desktop/software/test$ g++ bigone.cpp swag.cpp`
`~/Desktop/software/test$ ./a.out`
`swag`

And I'll look into cmake. Maybe that is just the best route.

Comment: I have the same problem, it just doesn't work :( Waste a whole day and nobody has the right answer.