# How to set up Visual Studio Code on Mac for linking multiple files during build?

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, g++, include-path

I am taking a C++, intro to CS class, and we are now starting to implement data abstraction for OOP. I am required to hide the class definitions in a separate .cpp file and to use a header file. Until now, I have been using the default settings in VSCode in my Macbook pro for creating single file programs, so I decided to create a test program to make sure the compilation, include and link would work properly before creating my entire project, but now when I try to build the program, I am receiving an error. I have tried for days to resolve the problem using potential solution without success. I am hoping someone here can lead me in the right direction.

I have included the contents of the 3 test files (test.cpp, test.h and testImp.cpp), the c_cpp_properties.json, launch.json, settings.json and task.json files and the content of the error message.

Any assistance setting up VSCode to complete including header files would be greatly appreciated since I will be having more projects with this requirement.

Thank you, James.

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << testCalculation(5, 7) << endl;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

test.h

```
#ifndef test_h
#define test_h

int testCalculation(int, int);

#endif /* test_h */
```

testImp.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

int testCalculation(int x, int y) {
int sum = int();
    sum = x + y;
    return sum;
};
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

setting.json

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "iostream": "cpp"
    }
}
```

task.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

ERROR

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /Users/jamesreal/cpp/cs-2/project-1/test.cpp -o /Users/jamesreal/cpp/cs-2/project-1/test
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "testCalculation(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-5cbf98.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Your bug is here: `"${file}",` It means that you want to build only the active file into the executable. The documentation tells you how to fix to build all of your files here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: @drescherjm, I can't thank you enough. I spent a lot of time trying to resolve this. I knew the answer was in the documentation somewhere, but I had no idea where to look. I appreciate you.  Thank you ,thank you, thank you.  Stay well.

Comment: If you have multiple cpp files use a build tool: Make, CMake, .....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use visual studio code to compile multi-cpp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720769/how-to-use-visual-studio-code-to-compile-multi-cpp-file)

Comment: It took me a some time to find but I believe the above link is a reasonable duplicate.

Comment: @drescherjm, yes, that helped. Thank you. There are a few sources in that single post that I will also review, but your first answer provided a solution. I appreciate the follow up and for providing further resources which provide a deeper look into the problem.  You rock!

Answer (score -1):

-1.Bro.

Your configuration files are the `Only one file` to build, compile and debug, NOT your wanted `multiple sources files'`.

0.First See

First, you were wrong in naming "`settings.json`" as "`setting.json`";

Also, you were wrong in naming "`tasks.json`" as "`task.json`".

1.Your Project

As your project Architecture `test` shows,

```
test

|

|_.vscode

|     |__c_cpp_properties.json

|     |__launch.json

|     |__settings.json

|     |__tasks.json

|__test.cpp

|__test.h

|__testImp.cpp
```

3.Solutions:

There are three ways to set up multiple source files build with

VSCode.

The one is to write terminal commands to "`settings.json`" and

"`tasks.json`" + "`launch.json`" + "`c_cpp_properties.json`";

The two is to write "`Makefile`" file via `make` to do that;

The three is to write "`CMakeList.txt`" via `CMake` to do that.

Now, I just share the first solution.

4.My workspace Environment with VSCode on mac

I just use `Clang9.0.0` to compile, `Code Runner v0.11.6` to

run program, `CodeLLDB v1.4.5` to debug, `C/C++ Clang Command Adopter`

`v0.2.4`(VSCode Extension) to provide static detection with VSCode on mac.

Maybe you use `cpptools`(`cpptools` is used to debug, This `CPPtools`

and that `CodeLLDB` conflict. ), that doesn't matter, just change

"type" from "lldb" to "cppdbg" in "`launch.json`".

5.My solution

This is a problem about multiple source files under the same folder to compile and debug with VSCode on mac.

I always firstly config `settings.json`. That shows like:

"`settings.json`", Just watch out for the "`code-runner.executorMap`".

Big Notices: This is "`settings.json`". Not "`setting.json`"!!!

```
{
    "files.defaultLanguage": "c++",
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
    // 3.Mutiple sourece C/C++ files under same folder build, compile, debug...
    // if put main.o and debug folder into the current directory "./"
    "c": "cd $dir && clang -std=c11 -stdlib=libc++  $dir/*.c  -o $dir/$fileNameWithoutExt && $dir/$fileNameWithoutExt", // Have changed
    "cpp": "cd $dir && clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++  $dir/*.cpp -o $dir/$fileNameWithoutExt && $dir/$fileNameWithoutExt" // Have changed
    },
    "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
    "code-runner.preserveFocus": false,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": false,
    "code-runner.ignoreSelection": true,
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_sortIncludes": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "clang.cxxflags": [
        "-std=c++11"
    ],
    "clang.cflags": [
        "-std=c11"
    ],
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "[makefile]": {
        "editor.insertSpaces": true
    },
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}"
    ],
    "clang.completion.enable": true
}
```

If you use `gcc/g++`, just change the `clang/clang++` to those.

If this line code needs to change or function, I add the comment

"`// Have changed`". Just notices that line code! Please!

"`tasks.json`": You know, that's "`tasks.json`"!!! NOT "`task.json`".

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "Compile With clang++",
      //"command": "clang++",/usr/bin/clang++
      "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
      "args": [
        "-std=c++11",
        "-stdlib=libc++",
        // My project fitBodyBootCamp were under 
        // /Users/marryme/VSCode/CppProject/fitBodyBootCamp
        // So ${workspcaeFolder} also were
        // /Users/marryme/VSCode/CppProject/fitBodyBootCamp
        // all the *.cpp files were under
        // /Users/marryme/VSCode/CppProject/fitBodyBootCamp
        "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp", // Have changed
        "-o",
        // Thanks those chiense website bloggers!
        // 1.mac vscode compile c++ multi-directory code demo
        // https://blog.csdn.net/fangfengzhen115/article/details/121496770?utm_medium=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-2~default~baidujs_baidulandingword~default-4.pc_relevant_default&spm=1001.2101.3001.4242.3&utm_relevant_index=7
        // 2.Compile and debug c++ multi-folder project under VSCode (non-makefile)
        // https://blog.csdn.net/BaiRuichang/article/details/106463035
        // I also put the main.o under my current workspace directory
        // This after "-o"  is the target file test.o or test.out or test
        "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}", // Have changed
        "-I",
        // This after "-I" if the include files directory
        "${workspaceFolder}", // Have changed
        "-Wall",
        "-g"
      ],
      "options": {
        // "cwd" is the source files directory
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}" // Have changed
      },
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

"`launch.json`":

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug With LLDB",
      "type": "lldb",
      "request": "launch",
      // "program" is the target file diretory
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}", // Have changed
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": true,
      //"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/../build",// Have changed
      //"cwd": "${fileDirName}", ${workspaceFolder}/../build
      // Changes the current working directory directive ("cwd") to the folder
      // where main.cpp is.
      // This "cwd" is the same as "cwd" in the tasks.json 
      // That's the source files directory
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}", // Have changed
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "preLaunchTask": "Compile With clang++"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, "c_cpp_properties.json"

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Mac",
      "includePath": [
        // This is the include files directory
        "${workspaceFolder}/**", // Have Change
        "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include",
        "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/include",
        "/usr/local/include",
        "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1",
        "/usr/include"
      ],
      "defines": [],
      "macFrameworkPath": [
        "/System/Library/Frameworks",
        "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks",
        "/Library/Frameworks"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
      "cStandard": "c11",
      "cppStandard": "c++11",
      "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

Notices:

You only need to modify the `Include path` setting if your program includes

header files that are not in your workspace or the standard library path.

Especially: `"includePath": [ "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/include"]`.

If your separated Command-line tools's Clang version is `9.0.0`, copy this program

directly.

If not, just use this command to checkout the Clang version of your separated

Command-line tools:

`cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/ && ls`

That may show like this: `9.0.0` or `9.1.0` or `10.0.0` or X.X.X. As this may show,

The Clang version of your separated Command-line tools is `9.0.0`, or `9.0.1` or

`10.0.0` or `X.X.X`. And just replace my `9.0.0`.

If you do not have a separated Command-line tool, just install [a separated command](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command%20line%20tools)

line tools for your Mac depending on your macOS system.

I will add the 5 files via adding the file.

END.

Finally,

If you need to build separated multiple source files,

that architecture just likes:

```
fitBody

|

|_.vscode

|     |__c_cpp_properties.json

|     |__launch.json

|     |__settings.json

|     |__tasks.json

|__build

|__inc

|     |__fitbody.h

|__src

     |__fitbody.cpp
 
     |__main.cpp
```

Please just make reference to [Separated Multiple CXX Manually](https://gist.github.com/SofijaErkin/2da5fb812f548282033a7f6b83327f19) VScode(mac) from GitHub Gist.

Or, make reference to [Separated Multiple CXX Manually VScode](https://github.com/SofijaErkin/basic-tool-mac/tree/main/vscode/build_compile_debug_case_combat/sepratedMultiSrcFiles)(mac)
from GitHub.