# VSCode - getting rid of quotation marks when using asterisk in tasks.json

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang++

I am trying to compile multiple files with VSCode on MacOS and modified the tasks.json as follows:

```
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${fileDirname}/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-I/${workspaceFolder}/include"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

The issue I am having is, that when I now click the run button, it runs the following command in the shell:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g 'some_path/*.cpp' -o some_path/main -I/some_other_path
```

So my problem is, that it puts quotation marks around `some_path/*.cpp` which makes the terminal think that the actual name of the file I want to compile is "*.cpp".
If I put the name of a specific file instead of asterisk in the "args"-value, it does not put quotation marks:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g some_path/main.cpp -o some_path/main -I/some_other_path
```

How can I prevent VSCode from making quotation marks when I want to use an asterisk?

**Edit:** Replacing * with ** does not work for me as suggested here: [VS Code will not build c++ programs with multiple .cpp source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665886/vs-code-will-not-build-c-programs-with-multiple-cpp-source-files)

**Edit2 Solution:** Just found a solution. Setting the type-property to "shell" instead of "cppbuild" gets the job done. Not sure though what "cppbuild" actually even does or refers to as it seems to me that it still just simply tries to run the command in the shell.

Comment: try to construct the full command in the `command` property, do not use `args`, or use a build tool

Comment: RTM `*` must be `**` in tasks.json.

Comment: The official documentation says to use `"${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp"` [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: Does `some_path` contain a space character? Perhaps that is what is causing the issue.

Comment: Weird. If ** doesn't work for you, I will reopen the Q.

Comment: ** instead of * doesn't work for me, I have seen that post. It will just write to the terminal '/some_path/**.cpp'.

Comment: @drescherjm Path does not contain spaces. I am pretty sure it makes the quotation marks because of the asterisk, which is driving me crazy.

Comment: @rioV8 Funny enough, if I put all arguments directly in the ```command``` property, it will put the whole command in quotations marks:
```'/usr/bin/clang++ -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g ${fileDirname}/*.cpp -o ${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension} -I/${workspaceFolder}/include'``` So that does not work neither.

Comment: @273K I've added another [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720769/how-to-use-visual-studio-code-to-compile-multi-cpp-file) that solve OP's problem.

Comment: This is odd that the official documentation does not work. I don't have a  macOS device so I can't test. I use linux and MS Windows.

Comment: VSC tries to guess what argument to quote, it does quote everything, it should let the user determine what to quote and if he wants to quote, they don't have the option of `complete command` (do not alter) and also they try to keep the environment the same when you use `env` (also means trouble for the rest of the command) the maintainer of that part of the code is not open for changes